# Can't find /Users folder on ubuntu "app" in Windows 11

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I am trying to access a file in my downloads folder via ubuntu WSL,I used `cd /mnt/Users/Omar/downloads`
But it says that the directory doesn't exist, I tried going in one folder at a time and found out the problem is `/Users`  does not exist.
I have all features enabled and ubuntu is up to date.
Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Ubuntu uses FHS so obviously it doesn't have `/Users` like macOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the `Users` folder in Windows is under the `C:\` drive, which is accessed in WSL via (by default) `/mnt/c`.  So your path should be something more like:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Omar/downloads
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still lost, try to list the folders you're trying to access by using the command:

```
ls /mnt/c/Users
```

You'll get then a view of where you'll need to go.

[image]

In this example, you can see `Public` and `cwm`, which is the name of the user in the Windows side.